# Rails 3.1.3 production, asset pipeline: no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, production-environment

I had set in my `production.rb` this:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

But the I'm still getting this error while using images recently uploaded by user

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I've tested this running with passenger on the server on production environment and I've tested this this on production with `WEBrick` on my local machine.

===== SOLVED =======

Fixed my situation with this settings on my `production.rb`

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false
```

Comment: THANKS for coming back to document that - I spent hours with same issue until I saw your post.

Comment: I don't think you're getting any benefit from precompiling static assets. I believe you're essentially falling back to the non-precompiled assets since it cannot find the them. This is like running your app in development mode.

Comment: @henry74 the only benefit in this case is that I won't get an error when trying to load recently uploaded images otherwise I'd have to precompile assets on every upload and that's not the way to go on a production server. a better aproach would be using an separate assets server like Amazon's S3 `Simple Storage Service` to serve assets and leave the app as it is with internal assets precompiled.

Comment: You may be missing the benefit of precomiling assets.  This is not just image files - this includes javascript and css files which can change.  When you precompile assets it does a few things like put all the javascript/css files into a single files and give special URLs to each static asset (css, js, images). In addition, it replaces all asset references in view files with the new URLs.  This acts as a cache buster so files that change (which they will if you change js/css) will be reloaded. Performance-wise compiled assets have no cache expiration so don't require a cache check (304 return).

Comment: Setting digest to false is probably not very good as your client won't be able to fetch updated version of your assets if they think they're cached.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to me if you don't serve_static_assets :

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

This behavior is the default.

Comment: but this would mess up with the `css` and `js` ?